# Minimize $\vert \vert B^HS BX\vert \vert$ subject to sparsity constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Can somebody please tell me if there is any iterative algorithm to solve the following optimization problem:

Given a collection of vectors in a matrix $X =\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=1}^q \in\mathbf{C}^{n\times q} $ such that $n>q$  and some other matrix $B \in \mathbf{C}^{m\times n}$ such that $m >n$, how do I solve for $S \in \mathcal{S}$  such that the norm $\vert \vert B^H S BX\vert \vert_{??}$  is minimized subject to the following condition:

1. $y_i:= B^H S Bx_i$ is as sparse as possible.
2. $ B^H SB$ is unitary

$\mathcal{S} = \left\{ S\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m} \mid S \quad \text{is diagonal} \right\}$

I would appreciate it if somebody could suggest me the norm that I could use for minimization and also the restriction on the set $\mathcal{S}$.